# Executing Unix/arbitrary commands on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, process

This is not for a production application - I'm just tinkering for the fun of it (on a device, not the simulator).

Is there any mechanism for executing arbitrary binaries on iOS? Say, `ls`.

I've tried `posix_spawn()`, but it always returns a status of `1`.

`system()` doesn't even compile, it fails with: `'system' is unavailable: not available on iOS`

`fork()` is similarly not allowed

I realize it's a long-shot, but I have a couple (local/personal) projects that are written as pre-compiled ARM binaries and I'd love to have them available on my iPad. (Plus it's just a fun experiment.)

*Sidenote: I haven't jailbroken an iOS device in years and I'm hoping to avoid it - if the above isn't possible with stock iOS, I'll just sigh and move on.*

Comment: Sandboxed apps on a non-jailbroken device can't kick off other processes.

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy, that's the conclusion I'm finding from pretty much every resource I read. I suppose I was holding out hope that there was some workaround/low-level API that is _usable_ on devices, but would understandably fail the App Store review. Sounds like we'll just have to wait for "developer mode" :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a project called ***[Linux shell for iOS](https://github.com/tbodt/ish)*** on GitHub to get a Linux shell running on iOS, using `usermode x86` emulation and `syscall` translation.

> You'll need these things to build the project:
>
> - Python 3
> - Ninja
> - Yarn (only when building for iOS)
> - Meson (pip install meson)
> - Clang and LLD (on mac, brew install llvm, on linux, sudo apt install clang lld or sudo pacman -S clang lld or whatever)
> - sqlite3 (this is so common it may already be installed on linux and is definitely already installed on mac. if not, do something like sudo apt install libsqlite3-dev)

I found this GitHub link in [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/284556/can-i-run-a-terminal-on-ios-with-sandboxed-filesystem-w-o-jailbreak) post.

P.S. I'm glad it's running.

[image]

Comment: This is 100% wizardry. It definitely takes some knowledge of Xcode to get the project building and launching, but it took me < 20 minutes to get this going on my iPad Pro: https://imgur.com/a/O8SO99u **Yes,** that's a Python web server running on the device itself. I can't believe this project didn't turn up in my searching. Things like `make` and `gcc` work as well. The only thing that hasn't worked in my limited testing so far is `java`, but there's an open issue for that: https://github.com/tbodt/ish/issues/306